# Geometric meaning of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $Q = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x,y > 0 \}$ be a vector space over the real numbers with the operations
$$+:Q\times Q \rightarrow Q$$
$$(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2,y_1y_2)$$
and
$$\cdot : \mathbb{R} \times Q \rightarrow Q$$
$$c\cdot(x,y)=(x^c,y^c)$$

It's easy to show that this structure is a vector space, but what about the geometrical meaning of these operations? Is there any?

Comment: what do you mean $x^c$

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^{c} x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\tilde x = \ln x$ and $\tilde y = \ln y$. Then $(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ is just the standard $\mathbb R^2$. Therefore your vector space is just the standard $\mathbb R^2$ using logarithmic coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb R_{> 0} = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x > 0 \}$.
Note that $\log\colon (\mathbb R_{>0},\cdot) \to \mathbb (\mathbb R,+)$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups.
This induces an isomorphism $Q=\mathbb R_{>0}^2 \to \mathbb R^2, (x,y) \mapsto (\log x, \log y)$.

Now note that under this isomorphism, your scalar multiplication becomes the usual one on $\mathbb R^2$ since $\log(x^c) = c\log(x)$.

So $Q$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual $\mathbb R$-vector space structure.